# Count number of references in a multi-value lookup column

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column

I'm using SharePoint Online, and I have one list of meetings, and one list of people. Meeting has a multi-value lookup column of people, so that several people can be added to a meeting.

How would I go about adding a column to people, with a counter of how many meetings each person has been added to?

It seems to be impossible to simply add a lookup field counter - because the `Meeting.People` column is multi-value, I reckon. What other options do I have?